# Looking for a general theorem in Linear Algebra about the isomorphism between linear functions and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

I'd be thankful for a reference to the most general form of this theorem. If I'm not mistaken, it is true that

$$
\mathcal{L}(U_n, V_m) \cong M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{F}),
$$

where $U_n$ is a $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$, $V_m$ is a $m$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$, and $\mathcal{L}$ is the set of linear functions between them. My end goal is to see the formal justification for working with matrices instead of general vector spaces. I already have an intuitive grasp of it, but I'd like to understand it in detail.

Comment: Well, what do you know about it? You have had some explanation about it already, so for us to answer your question we should know what "detail" is missing that you'd like to fill in.

Answer (score 0):

What you've written is pretty much the most general form of the theorem. To prove it,  the
definition of dimension says you can  choose bases with $m$ and $n$ elements for the domain and codomain. That coordinatization leads to the identification of linear transformations with matrices.

Comment: It's unclear to me what structure these two sets have, and hence I don't know what form the isomorphism must be. Also, I don't think that this is the most general statement, since it doesn't deal with the fact that composition of functions carries over to the product of matrices.

Comment: You can find a proof that function composition corresponds to matrix multiplication in any reasonable linear algebra text and on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: Both sides are vector spaces, so it is a vector space iso.  (It becomes a ring when $U=V$ because then all linear maps may be composed.)